# Three.js specific render-time uniforms

Tags: three.js

I want to implement per-object motion-blur effect based on  calculating previous pixel position inside shaders.

This technic's first step is to build velocity map of moving objects. This step requirements is to have as uniform variables projection and model view matrices of current frame and the same matrices of previous frame.

How could I include those matrices to uniforms for some special shader? I supposed to have solution in some way like:

```
 uniforms = {
   some_uniform_var : {type: "m4", value: initialMatrix, getter: function(){
      // `this` points to object
      return this.worldMatrix
   }}
 }
```

But now in THREE.js this is not available. We could make some sort of monkey patching, but I cannot find best way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to pass an array of `Matrix4`? You can do that with type `m4v`. Just update the array values inside the render loop.

Comment: Yes, i want. Problem is, that I want to: 1- pass this matrix to uniforms for certain material, which would be overrided material. 2 - this matrix MUST be passed for each object in the scene. 3 - I don't want to have special loop in userspace to walk through each object, when renderer itself does it.

Comment: I do not understand. Try to provide a working live example (even if it loops through each object). Then ask a specific question about it.

Comment: I'll try to explaing this in answer. And, It would be nice, if you could give opinion will it be a nie patch, or not...

Comment: Hmmm... From code fragments, it is difficult to comment... But I can only answer questions about three.js, anyway -- otherwise I'd never get anything done. :-)

Comment: Yep. But this is a very close question. And in the same time very few people will face it.

Answer (score 0):

The current solvation to this problems consist of several parts. I'm using EffectComposer to make several passes of rendered scene, one of then - VelocityPass. It takes current and previous model-view matrix and projection matrix and produces two positions. Both of them then used to calculate speed of a point.

Shader looks like this

```
    "void main() {",

        "vec2 a = (pos.xy / pos.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;",
        "vec2 b = (prevPos.xy / prevPos.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;",
        "vec2 oVelocity = a - b;",

        "gl_FragColor = vec4(oVelocity, 0.0, 1.);",

    "}"
```

There're several issues of this decision. 
Three.js has certain point where it injects matrices to object-related shaders. The very ending of `SetProgram` closure, which lives in `WebGLRenderer`. That's why I took the whole renderer file, renamed renderer to `THREE.MySuperDuperWebGLRenderer` and added couple lines of code in it:

A closure to access closures, defined in userspace:

```
function materialPerObjectSetup(material, object){
    if( material.customUniformUpdate ){
        material.customUniformUpdate( object, material, _gl ); // Yes, I  had to pass it...

    }

}
```

And calling of it in `renderBuffer` and `renderBufferDirect`;

```
    var program = setProgram( camera, lights, fog, material, object );

    materialPerObjectSetup(material, object);
```

Now - the userspace part:

```
velocityMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( THREE.VelocityShader );

velocityMat.customUniformUpdate = function(obj, mat, _gl){

    // console.log("gotcha");
    var new_m = obj.matrixWorld;
    var p_uniforms = mat.program.uniforms;
    var mvMatrix = camera.matrixWorldInverse.clone().multiplyMatrices(camera.matrixWorldInverse, obj._oldMatrix );

    _gl.uniformMatrix4fv( p_uniforms.prevModelViewMatrix, false,  mvMatrix.elements );
    _gl.uniformMatrix4fv( p_uniforms.prevProjectionMatrix, false, camera.projectionMatrix.elements );
    obj._pass_complete = true; // Необходимо сохранять состояние старой матрицы пока не отрисуется этот пасс. 
                               // А то матрицы обновляются каждый рендеринг сцены.
}
```

`_pass_complete` needed when we rerendering scene several times - each time matrix recalculated. This trick help us save previous matrix untill we use it.

`_gl.uniformMatrix4fv` is needed, because three.js serves universes one time before rendering. No matter how much objects we have - other method will pass to the shader `modelViewMatrix` of the last one. This happens because I want to draw this scene fully using `VelocityShader`. There's no other way to say to Renderer to use some alternative material for objects.

And as final point of this explaination I putting here a trick to manage previous matrix of an object:

```
            THREE.Mesh.prototype._updateMatrixWorld = rotatedObject.updateMatrixWorld;
            THREE.Mesh.prototype._pass_complete = true;

            Object.defineProperty(THREE.Mesh.prototype, "updateMatrixWorld", {get: function(){
                if(this._pass_complete){
                    this._oldMatrix = this.matrixWorld.clone();
                    this._pass_complete = false;
                }

                this._updateMatrixWorld();


                return (function(){
                });


            }})
```

I believe, that there's could be a nicer solution. But sometimes I need to act in rush. And such kind of monkey things could happen.

Comment: "It takes current and previous model-view matrix and projection matrix and produces two positions."

Can you elaborate on this? vec4 pos, prevPos is the vertex transformation? I'm not sure what the question is here. If you have to clone these matrices in each object anyway, what is preventing you from passing / updating them in regards to the shader?

Comment: First obstacle - is overriding material - we getting one material for every object. With one uniforms array. The last object in rendering sequence wins. Second - is that we don't have control over sending matrices to shader in the most suitable moment for this. Common uniforms sent far before this moment and THREE.js has incapsulated this and don't gives any callbacks.

Comment: any chance you could set up a fiddle? Or at least some screenshots?

Comment: I even have a working demo. Which is a bunch of "I should throw it away" code. http://stavenko.github.io/shader-develop.html. Basically you wanting to see `PerObjectBlurShader.js`, `VelocityPass.js`,  `VelocityShader.js`, `customWeGLRenderer.js`, and `shader-develop.html` itself. But I'd think twice before deeping in that...

Comment: And before exploring - here's an article which will give you understanding of the purpose of all this. http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/per-object-motion-blur.html

Comment: I read the article, and i'm looking at this code, and it just seems way too complicated. You render your geometry in a pass, within the same pass you do two transformations, and you process this in the fragment shader. Combining the two you get the image space velocity. Your question is where would be the best place to intercept this update and provide both matrices to the shader?

Comment: Yes.And of course this way very complicated. And at the same time I suspect, that there could be some way which does not involves direct usage of _gl object. You know, every framework could be hacked, but that's not what they designed for.

Comment: What is preventing you from running a loop across the objects, update the needed matrices (this is not camera blur, it's object blur, you're  blurring based on the world transformation?) and then just assign it to the custom uniform? It seems to me that you can do everything that you're doing a level above this, and avoid hacking the _gl much. Although, for this effect, you could look into the deferred renderer.

Comment: I guess you could end up setting a lot of copies of the same material in a more complex setup. But this happens under the hood in any case, so you're probably doing the right thing with your 'hack'. It seems that you know quite a bit about this stuff, so if you didn't come across a cleaner hook in the code already, there probably isn't any.